# Как пометить класс как [Serializable] ,если он подгружается из dll

Tags: c#, сериализация, serializable

Я использую dll файлы в моем проекте. Как пометить класс как сериализуемый атрибутом [serializable].
Я не имею исходного кода, только dll файл, на который есть ссылка в моем классе.
Я хочу сделать его сериализуемым, чтобы использовать состояние представления для моего объекта, который использует dll. Использую бинарную сериализацию.
Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы можете вручную, кодом, извлечь из такого объекта все нужные свойства, то можно использовать механизм [Surrogate Selector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.surrogateselector(v=vs.110).aspx). Код честно взят из MSDN. `Employee` - тот самый "внешний" класс, на который нельзя поставить `[Serializable]`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;


// This class is not serializable.
class Employee 
{
    public String name, address;

    public Employee(String name, String address) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
}

// This class can manually serialize an Employee object.
sealed class EmployeeSerializationSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate 
{

    // Serialize the Employee object to save the object's name and address fields.
    public void GetObjectData(Object obj, 
        SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
    {

        Employee emp = (Employee) obj;
        info.AddValue("name", emp.name);
        info.AddValue("address", emp.address);
    }

    // Deserialize the Employee object to set the object's name and address fields.
    public Object SetObjectData(Object obj,
        SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context,
        ISurrogateSelector selector) 
    {

        Employee emp = (Employee) obj;
        emp.name = info.GetString("name");
        emp.address = info.GetString("address");
        return null;
    }
}

public sealed class App 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        // This sample uses the BinaryFormatter.
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Create a MemoryStream that the object will be serialized into and deserialized from.
        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream()) 
        {
            // Create a SurrogateSelector.
            SurrogateSelector ss = new SurrogateSelector();

            // Tell the SurrogateSelector that Employee objects are serialized and deserialized 
            // using the EmployeeSerializationSurrogate object.
            ss.AddSurrogate(typeof(Employee),
            new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All),
            new EmployeeSerializationSurrogate());

            // Associate the SurrogateSelector with the BinaryFormatter.
            formatter.SurrogateSelector = ss;

            try 
            {
                // Serialize an Employee object into the memory stream.
                formatter.Serialize(stream, new Employee("Jeff", "1 Microsoft Way"));
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Serialization failed: {0}", e.Message);
                throw;
            }

            // Rewind the MemoryStream.
            stream.Position = 0;

            try 
            {
                // Deserialize the Employee object from the memory stream.
                Employee emp = (Employee) formatter.Deserialize(stream);

                // Verify that it all worked.
                Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Address = {1}", emp.name, emp.address);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deserialization failed: {0}", e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

// This code produces the following output.
//
// Name = Jeff, Address = 1 Microsoft Way
```

т.е. сериализоваться будет класс без аттрибута `[Serializable]`, но как именно его сериализовать - вам придется описать самому.

Comment: Это плохое решение. По сути - вы предлагаете использовать `BinaryFormatter` и подменить его поведение ровно для одного случая, для которого вы предлагаете его использовать. Это было бы решением, если отказаться от использования `BinaryFormatter` было нельзя, или если бы экземпляр нашего класса был бы значением какого-то поля/свойства другого класса, который нужно сохранить, используя `BinaryFormatter` (именно для этого нужны суррогаты).

Comment: @PavelHritonenko я не утверждаю что это решение хорошее или оптимальное в любом возможном случае. но тем не менее - это решение :)

Comment: вы же сами пишете "но как именно его сериализовать - вам придется описать самому". Вопрос, зачем тогда весь этот мусорный код с `BinaryFormatter`? Какое отношение оно имеет  к изначальному вопросу?

Answer (score 4):

Атрибуты класса лежат в метаданных, которые лежат внутри скомпилированной сборки, то есть пометить класс как `[Serializable]` у вас не получится.

Пользуйтесь сериализатором, который не смотрит на эти аттрибуты.

Comment: Именно в этом и проблема, и что с этим делать ?

Comment: Опишите, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать с экземпляром этого класса, что такое "состояние представления"? Если сохранить в набор байтов и потом восстановить - воспользуйтесь просто другим сериализатором.  `ServiceStack.Text`, `Json.NET`, `FsPickler`, тысячи их

Comment: Да, сохранить в набор байтов и потом восстановить:)

Comment: Т.е вы предлагаете использовать сериализатор контрактов данных?

Comment: @G4us а вариант с суррогатом вам не подошел? м.б. проще, чем поменять сериализатор :)

Comment: @PashaPash а чем этот вариант отличается от предложенного мной? Ваш вариант заключается в том, чтобы использовать `BinaryFormatter` и затем хакать его поведение, потому что вы используете его не по назначению (не для сериализации `[Serializable]` классов). Моё предложение заключается в том, чтобы  сразу использовать сериализатор, который обнаруживает структуру данных через рефлексию.

Comment: @G4us, я не знаю контекста вашей задачи, поэтому не могу предложить конкретное решение. Я не знаю, что к примеру будет, если вы обновите версию DLL, которую используете, какое ожидаемое поведение должно быть. Возможно, в вашем случае будет правильным считать состояние вашего экземпляра через публичные поля, сохранить их куда-нибудь (например, сериализовав DTO-класс их содержащий). Ну и восстановить экземпляр исходного класса вызовом соответствующего конструктора. Конкретное решение зависит от многих деталей.

Comment: @PavelHritonenko BinaryFormatter тоже использует рефлексию. Просто сохранение влоб всех полей через рефлексию не дает гарантии корректной сериализации. Поэтому BF (и многие другие) требуют явной отметки что класс можно сериализовать.  Заменить сериализатор - да, вполне нормальный вариант. Но он может быть не самым простым. Я предложил вариант, который проще в реализации в случае "все классы сериализуются нормально, кроме одного". И который позволяет сериализовать дерево объектов, содержащее не-Serialized вещи. А вы у себя в ответе утверждаете что это невозможно :)

Comment: @PavelHritonenko хотя лично я, если честно, поменял бы сериализатор. BinaryFormatter - это просто древняя глючная жесть. Особенно когда дело доходит до смены версии сборки.

Comment: @PashaPash одно замечание - я не утверждал, что это невозможно.